# Compiling altcoin (based on litecoin) wallet on windows undefined reference to `leveldb

Tags: windows, mingw, bitcoin, leveldb, bitcoind

I am following the write up detailed here
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=149479.0
but I seem to be having some issues with the last step of compiling on windows. When attempting to compile an altcoin wallet (based on litecoin), I keep receiving the following error

```
C:\testcoin\src>mingw32-make -f makefile.mingw
g++ -mthreads -O2 -w -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parame
ter -g -D_MT -DWIN32 -D_WINDOWS -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE
```

-DUSE_IPV6=1 -IC:/testcoin/src/leveldb/include -IC:/testcoin/src/leveldb/helpers -
    I"C:/testcoin/src" -I"c:/deps/boost_1_55_0" -I"c:/deps/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix" -I
    "c:/deps/openssl-1.0.1e/include" -I"c:/deps/libpng-1.6.8" -I"c:/deps/qrencode-3.
    4.3" -I"c:/deps/protobuf-2.5.0/src" -I"/usr/local/include" -I"c:/testcoin/src/leve
    ldb/include" -I"c:/testcoin/src/leveldb/" -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat -Wl,--l
    arge-address-aware -static -o testcoind.exe -L"C:/testcoin/src/leveldb" -L"c:/deps/b
    oost_1_55_0/stage/lib" -L"c:/deps/db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix" -L"c:/deps/openssl-1.
    0.1e" -L"c:/deps/libpng-1.6.8/libs" -L"c:/deps/qrencode-3.4.3/libs" -L"c:/deps/p
    rotobuf-2.5.0/src/libs"  leveldb/libleveldb.a obj/alert.o obj/version.o obj/chec
    kpoints.o obj/netbase.o obj/addrman.o obj/crypter.o obj/key.o obj/db.o obj/init.
    o obj/keystore.o obj/main.o obj/net.o obj/protocol.o obj/bitcoinrpc.o obj/rpcdum
    p.o obj/rpcnet.o obj/rpcmining.o obj/rpcwallet.o obj/rpcblockchain.o obj/rpcrawt
    ransaction.o obj/script.o obj/scrypt.o obj/sync.o obj/util.o obj/wallet.o obj/wa
    lletdb.o obj/hash.o obj/bloom.o obj/noui.o obj/leveldb.o obj/txdb.o -l boost_sys
    tem-mgw48-mt-s-1_55 -l boost_filesystem-mgw48-mt-s-1_55 -l boost_program_options
    -mgw48-mt-s-1_55 -l boost_thread-mgw48-mt-s-1_55 -l db_cxx -l leveldb -l boost_c
    hrono-mgw48-mt-s-1_55 -l ssl -l crypto -l mingwthrd -l kernel32 -l user32 -l gdi
    32 -l comdlg32 -l winspool -l winmm -l shell32 -l comctl32 -l ole32 -l oleaut32
    -l uuid -l rpcrt4 -l advapi32 -l ws2_32 -l mswsock -l shlwapi
    obj/leveldb.o: In function `ZN8CLevelDBC2ERKN5boost10filesystem4pathEjbb':
    c:\testcoin\src/leveldb.cpp:46: undefined reference to`leveldb::NewMemEnv(leveldb
    ::Env*)'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    makefile.mingw:144: recipe for target 'testcoind.exe' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [testcoind.exe] Error 1

This is on a windows virtual machine in which I followed the directions exactly as typed. Thanks for your time and any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question but thought I'd post this anyway as it may help others who find this page.

You need to build leveldb. Go to the msys shell and copy and paste the following

```
cd /C/testcoin/src/leveldb

TARGET_OS=NATIVE_WINDOWS make libleveldb.a libmemenv.a
```